# standard score or p value

Tags: p-value

I have two groups of data, each contains five sets.
Each of them has a standard score.
I would like to compare them.

However I don't know if it is good to directly compare standard scores.
As you know, the difference in standard score -2 and -1 is different from -1 and 0.

So, should I use p value instead?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "compare them". What, precisely, is your question?

Comment: @jona two groups of students, wanting to compare their results in an exam to see which is better

Comment: for example, group 1 has two students, with standard scores 2.1 and 1.0. Group 2 has two students, with standard scores 2.2 and 0.9. Can I say which group is better, or they just have same performance?

Comment: Inferential statistics, such as the p value resulting from a t or z test, correspond to inferences of the value of a parameter in a population based on measured samples. If you only want to talk about the students you have measured, p values are hard to interpret. Are z values useful here? Not inherently, it really depends on what precisely your question is. If you want to infer populations based on the sample, p values can become useful, but again, first you need a more precise question.

Comment: What is the distinction you are making between "groups" and "sets"?  Are you simply saying you have two collections of five numbers each?

Comment: @whuber yes. sorry for the inaccuracy.